# networkX add edges on a graph stored in file without load it

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I do some stuff with a big graph with more than 25000 nodes. I must add edges in a for/if loop but the common way kick my memory out!!

I think it possible to write the base graph into a file, and just write in it the correct "string" to add edges. In this way the graph will never loaded entirely and it sve my memory for other calculations.

Had someone a simple code to do that?

Thks!

---

**edit:**

Here is the way I use actually, it's not very pythonnic, but it does the job... If you see a better solution I'm in.

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(n)
nx.write_multiline_adjlist(G,"node.adjlist")

#create the node file

nodefile = open('node.adjlist', 'r')
edgefile = open('edge.adjlist', 'w')
for i, line in enumerate(nodefile):
  if i < 3:
  edgefile.write('%s\n' % (line.rstrip('\n')))
nodefile.close()
edgefile.close()

#remove the last line of the created file

for n in itertools.combinations(xrange(n), 2):
   (i, j) result
   edgefile = open('edge.adjlist', 'a')
   if first_time_i_is_called():
     edgefile.write('\n' + str(i))
   for element in some_enorm_calculs_based_on_i_and_j:
     if element not in list_of_good_answers:
        count = 1
        break
     if count == 0:
        edgefile.write(' ' + str(j))
   edgefile.close()
```

Comment: You don't need to add the edges in a for loop, networkX supports many formats for storing and loading edge lists which should be efficient enough, have you checked the docs: http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/readwrite.html

Comment: The loop is a necessity for knowing if their is an edge or not. At beginning I store information in a matrix before translate to a graph. But the matrix is an unnecessary step. So I will by-pass it by creating edge if my loop said so. The problem is that storing the graph and do the calculation of if their is an edge or not need too much memory.

Comment: Can you tell us how it is stored in the file and why it has to be stored in that format?  A common way to store a graph is simply a list of nodes and then a list of edges.  No need to store anything else.

Comment: For the storage I have no preference. But finally I use the multiline_adjiline export after node creation than I open it like a text file and append node number when necessary. It's not very pythonic but it works...

Comment: There's just not enough information for me to figure out what the trouble is.  I don't know enough about what you're doing to understand what the problem is or why it's occurring.  You'll have to provide enough code for us to see what's happening.